# Printing with fixed spaces

Tags: c++, cout

I want to print two strings (say "ABC" and "DEF") with 5 space characters before "ABC" and that the second string will start 7 characters after the beginning of the first string.

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Comment: Also what should happen if the first string is greater than 7 characters? What string is supposed to be dominant over which other?

Comment: for simplicity, lets assume there is no problem with the sizes.

i know i can you left and setw, but i don't know how to combine it with the space in the left side

Comment: your question has an answer so simples as let say cout << "     ABC    DEF"; but if you have variable string sizes so you need some basic math, but i mean basic like really basic math ( for(i = 0; i < 7 - str1.size; i++) cout << " "; ) .

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you're looking for the width() method:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string abc = "ABC";
  string edf = "EDF";
  cout.width(8);
  cout << abc;
  cout.width(7);
  cout << edf;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{ 
char a[] = "ABC";
char b[] = "EDF";
cout<"     "<<a<<"       "<<b;
return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Not correct. b is printed 7 spaces after the __end__ of a here. It should be printed 7 spaces after the __beginning__ of a.